# Typescript 3: using project references

Tags: typescript

Trying to use the new project references feature in Typescript 3. I read [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) document about it which showed me how to modify the tsconfig.json files in each respective project, but it says nothing about how to actually make use of the feature, i.e. importing classes from the referenced project into the other project. Any guidance?

Comment: The easiest way to go about this is to make each project a separate package in a [monorepo](https://github.com/lerna/lerna)

Comment: I can look into this, but ideally if typescript has developed a way to handle this without external libraries we would like to explore that.